# google +1 button adds scroll bar to my site

Tags: html, layout, google-plus-one

I have had a google +1 button on my site for more then a year and it all worked fine.

In the last couple of days this button started to create a horizontal scroll bar on my site.

I know that beacase when I remove the button the scroll bar disappears.

Here is my site: [www.kitchen-guide.co.il](http://www.kitchen-guide.co.il)

Any suggestions what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: hebrew site! cool ive never seen that before

Comment: Very good information how i can add scrolling button to my blog this is my blog www.urexamsyllabus.blogspot.com

Comment: make body `overflow-x:hidden;`

Answer (score 12):

borrowing from superware's answer, was having the same problem... however, this worked for me:

```
iframe[id^="oauth2relay"] { position: fixed !important; }
```

Comment: For me worked changing position: fixed to display: none, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Google's +1 button is adding the following iframe to the end of the page body:

`<iframe name="oauth2relayXXXXXXXXX" id="oauth2relayXXXXXXXXX" src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com#rpctoken=XXXXXXXXX&amp;forcesecure=1" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; left: -100px;"></iframe>`

One workaround (to this Google bug) can be to include the following rule in your CSS:

`iframe[id^="oauth2relay"] { left: auto !important; right: -100px !important; }`

If your website is all RTL then it should work fine, but if it's also LTR (multilingual) you will have to somehow target that role on RTL pages only. Check [resizenow.com](http://www.resizenow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is no longer used to render the information bubble. 
therefor, the previously suggested solution will not work anymore.

To fix the issue define the `data-onendinteraction` callback attribute.

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-onendinteraction="gplusoneinteraction"></div>
```

Then, implement the interaction callback function:

```
window.gplusoneinteraction = function(params) {
    $('iframe[id^="oauth2relay"]').next('div').css({left: 0, right: '-10000px'});
}
```