# G+1 button during loading ads scrollbar to my site

Tags: css, html, layout, google-plus-one

My site have a main div with width set to ~1200px and centered.

if I put g+1 button inside another div which is float:left and div with content on the right side everything works great. Sadly, I would like to put this button on the right side of my content. In this situation during loading this button ads horizontal scrollbar for one second.

I know about this: [google +1 button adds scroll bar to my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437265/google-1-button-adds-scroll-bar-to-my-site)

but it not work for me.

I'm googling about it, but every solution is similar to this I linked above.

[EDIT] IE & FF only

Answer (score 0):

Only one solution I found is load g+1 button to hidden div, and show this div with some delay.

Social div contains three social-* divs for facebook, googleplus and twitter.

```
$('#social-fb').css("opacity", "0.0");
$('#social-gp').hide();
$('#social-tw').hide();

$('#social-fb').html('...');
$('#social-gp').html('...');
$('#social-tw').html('...');

timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
  $('#social').hide()
  $('#social-fb').css("opacity", "1.0");
  $('#social-gp').show();
  $('#social-tw').show(); 
  $('#social').fadeIn(500);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you please share how to do this?